# Difference on std::vector push_back(Object()) and push_back(new Object())?

Tags: c++, vector, insert, std

In my current code, I'm wanting to insert new DrawObjects into a vector I created,

std::vector< DrawObject > objects;

What is the difference between:

```
objects.push_back(DrawObject(name, surfaceFile, xPos, yPos, willMoveVar, animationNumber));
```

and

```
objects.push_back(new DrawObject(name, surfaceFile, xPos, yPos, willMoveVar, animationNumber));
```

Comment: One will compile, the other won't.

Comment: Alternatively, with that setup, one is more Java/C#, and the other is C++.

Comment: I don't see any sane way in which both of them would compile... Is `DrawObject` just a _class_? Is it _convertible_/_constructible_ from pointers?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First one adds **non-pointer** object, while the second one adds **pointer** to the vector. So it all depends on the declaration of the vector as to which one you should do.

In your case, since you have declared `objects` as `std::vector<DrawObject>`, so the first one will work, as `objects` can store items of type `DrawObject`, not `DrawObject*`.

In C++11, you can use `emplace_back` as:

```
objects.emplace_back(name, surfaceFile, xPos, yPos, 
                     willMoveVar, animationNumber);
```

Note the difference. Compare it with:

```
objects.push_back(DrawObject(name, surfaceFile, xPos, yPos, 
                            willMoveVar, animationNumber));
```

With `emplace_back`, you don't construct the object at the call-site, instead you pass the arguments to vector, and the vector internally constructs the object in place. In some cases, this could be faster.

Read the doc about [emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) which says (emphasize mine),

> Appends a new element to the end of the container. The element is constructed in-place, i.e. **no copy or move operations are performed**. The constructor of the element is called with *exactly the same arguments* that are supplied to the function.

As it avoids *copy* or *move*, the resultant code could be a bit faster.

Comment: Nice little shortcut there: any difference, besides syntax? Like, performance or something the like.

Comment: @user1896797: Yes, it might improve performance, as it avoids *copy* and even *move*.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
std::vector< DrawObject > objects;
```

The difference between the two versions is that the first one is correct, and the second one isn't.

If the second version compiles, as you indicate in the comments, it doesn't do what you expect it might. It also suggests that you should probably consider making some of `DrawObject`'s constructors `explicit`.

Answer (score 1):

The second version expects `objects` to be a vector of **pointers** to DrawObject, while the first one expects `objects` to hold the objects themselves. Thus depending on the declaration of `objects` only one of the versions will compile.

If you declare `objects` the way you did, only the first version will compile, if you declare objects as `std::vector< DrawObject*> objects;` only the second version will compile.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an object using the keyword `new` your allocating it on the heap. This will return a pointer to the object.

When as when you create an object without the keyword `new` it will get allocated on the stack and you will get access to that object in place.

Comment: That's bringing in a whole lot of irrelevant implementation details IMHO.

Comment: @delnan Ignorance is bliss.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question *completely*.

Comment: It did help me to realize I can create objects on the stack or heap, hadn't apply that logic to creating objects aswell
Might I have some issue since the object is being allocated on stack? When will it expire in these conditions? It's a long-life object

Comment: @user1896797 The life of an object on the stack is within it is scope (That is the brackets { } that it belongs in), on the heap it will live until you delete it using the delete key word.